# Next.js only loads global.css after manual page refresh. Another also existing styles.js is ignored

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, localhost, refresh

As of now the styling happens in two places: `global.css` + `index.js` via styled-components

#### Problem

After start or restart of local server + manual page refresh, all styles are applied as intended. Also style changes are applied promptly. 
Now, if **another** manual page refresh is performed, only styles from `global.css` are applied, but styles from `index.js` file don't initially load.
Styles other than `global.css` only take effect in 2 ways:

1. click one of the links + click on retun button (2nd screenshot)
2. restart local server + page refresh

I recorded the steps I make. Sorry for the breathing noise.  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cp-97ZYsQhw

I added the code snippets for a better code overview only. I'm trying to setup a working example on codesandbox.

#### Question

Why does next.js only load the global.css, but ignore the index.js with more css until either the local server is restarted or some links are clicked?

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledMain = styled.main`
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
`;

const StyledLi = styled.li`
    font-size: var(--fontsize-profileButtons);
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 50px 0; 
`;

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <>
            <StyledMain>
                <ul>
                    <StyledLi>
                        <Link href="/about">about</Link>
                    </StyledLi>
                    <StyledLi>
                        <Link href="/projects">projects</Link>
                    </StyledLi>
                    <StyledLi>
                        <Link href="/blog">blog</Link>
                    </StyledLi>
                </ul>
            </StyledMain>
        </>
    )
}
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

What `index.js` looks like after page refresh + what it's supposed to look like
[image]

Procedure to also load css code inside `index.js`
[image]

Comment: Its also happens to me now. v 13

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in v13.3.4 and loading my global.css file into a client-side component solved it. Not sure if this is an official solution, though.

Comment: Hi, you can improve your answer adding explanations,or documentation, because as is it's too vague

Answer (score 0):

Just add your library's css file import to _document.js file, ie

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css" />
```