# How to prop-drill varying hrefs for various Link-components down to the original Link component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, href, react-props, template-literals

#### [*Solution*]

Working solution suggested by @[Nikhil bhatia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293481/nikhil-bhatia) goes as follows. 
 Check original post further down below for alternative idea.

```js
export default function TopNav(props) {
    const { data } = props

    return (
      <StyledDiv>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            {data.map(item => <StyledLi key={item.name} >
              <Link href={item.href}>{item.name}</Link>
            </StyledLi> )}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </StyledDiv>
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

---

## Original Post

### Problem

I have one component that's supposed to be the scheme for how I want to display a list of links. These links differ depending on which site I am currently on.

On the main page I can choose from **about**, **projects**, **blog**. Depending on which I click on, I want the respective site to show 2 links to the other 2 pages.

[image]

Hence... the linkname + href props change for each of the 3 pages. 
So far I am passing the linkname through to the link-component, but how do I pass the href?

### Question

How do I drill the individual href down to the original Link-Component?

#### My solution so far

**Link-Component** 
I have tried template literals like this:

```
<Link href=`/{linkA_Url}`>{linkA}</Link>
```

```js
export default function TopNav({ linkA, linkB }) {
  return (
    <StyledDiv>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <StyledLi>
            <Link href="/">{linkA}</Link>
          </StyledLi>
          <StyledLi>
            <Link href="/">{linkB}</Link>
          </StyledLi>
          <StyledLi>
            <Link href="/">⬅</Link>
          </StyledLi>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </StyledDiv>
  );a
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Individual Component** 
The pages about, projects, blog use the `TopNav` Component shown above. Here's the about-page as example. I'm passing through the name of the link, but how I also pass the href?
It should be something like 
`<TopNav href="/projects" href="/blog" linkA="projects" linkB="blog" />`
The href props obviously need different names, so that's where the problem starts.

```js
export default function About({ title, linkA, linkB }) {

  return (
    <>
      <TopNav linkA="projects" linkB="blog" />
    </>
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[Link to Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/homepage-mkcxiu)

If the main page doesn't show the 3 links about, projects & blog centered in the middle, reload the preview window. This is another issue that I haven't managed to resolve either. [I've created a separate question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74578429/next-js-only-loads-global-css-after-manual-page-refresh-another-also-existing-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refractor TopNav like this

```html
export default function TopNav(props) {
    const { data } = props

    return (
      <StyledDiv>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            {data.map(item => <StyledLi key={item.name} >
              <Link href={item.href}>{item.name}</Link>
            </StyledLi> )}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </StyledDiv>
    );
}
```

now you can use it like <TopNav data={[{href: "/abc", name: "ABC"}, {href: "/xyz", name: "XYZ"}]} />

you can either use it on every page with different props,

or

you can use it on top level _app.jsx and give conditional data props to TopNav, you can get pathname from useRouter and depending upon the path name change data prop

example

```html
const App = () => {
 const { asPath } = useRouter()
 const getData = () => {
   if (asPath === "/url1") {
     return [{href: "/abc", name: "ABC" }]
   }
   if (asPath === "/url2") {
     return [{href: "/xyz", name: "XYZ" }]
   }
   return [{href: "/wsad", name: "WSAD" }]
 }
  return(
   <>
    <TapNav data={getData()} />    
    {otherComp}
   </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Firstly: Thanks! First version works nicely. I just forgot to add parenthesis initially, because I use line breaks.

Secondly: Could you elaborate on your second suggestion?

Comment: Thanks again! This looks like the least code redundant version I have seen so far. I'll try this asap. 
*Question:* I assume the return values inside an array in order to map over them?

Comment: thats right!!!!

Comment: I have a follow up question. In your last post you said **"you can use it on top level _app.jsx and give conditional data props to TopNav"**. Why does it have to be at the top level? I'm using next.js, so my top level (_app.js) looks slightly different. The only component _app.js returns is `<Component {...pageProps} />`. There are multiple implicit questions I have here, but if you could elaborate on that initial question (why top level), that alone would help.

Comment: why top level, it depends on your use case, I prefer it on top level, since I don't want my nav bar to be re-rendered every time user navigates to different page, it can give a flickering effect, or imagine there is some search bar in your nav bar and you want to retain search on next page, but if it is re-rendered you will lose its state data, so just above <Component {...pageProps} /> you can add <TopNav />